# Dbus doesn't see ru.gentoo.KbddService on startup

Tags: linux, i3

I have installed Xubuntu 16.04, later I installed i3wm and I like it. But, there is one interesting issue. I use kbdd and setxkbmap for switching and controlling keyboard layouts. So, I put this in **~/.xsessionrc**:

```
#!/bin/sh
kbdd
exec setxkbmap "us,ua,ru" ",winkeys" "grp:shift_caps_toggle" &
dropbox start &
```

It all works, but when I tried to add my own "current layout indicator" to i3bar via dbus:

```
dbus-send --print-reply=literal --dest=ru.gentoo.KbddService /ru/gentoo/KbddService ru.gentoo.kbdd.getCurrentLayout | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

it shows an error:

```
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name ru.gentoo.KbddService was not provided by any .service files
```

But if I start from terminal kbdd again, it works! Also, pid of kbdd doesn't change at all. So, problem probably in order of starting something.
BTW, on another computer I use blank login and startx command to start i3, so I use ~/.xinitrc instead of ~/.sessionrc and it works perfectly.
Could anyone help?

Appendix:

pid of kbdd is lesser than pid of dbus-launcher, but pid of dbus-monitor is lesser than pid of kbdd. Seems, like this is a reason.  But why? Should I write some unit-script for systemd to start kbdd after dbus-launcher of something else?